# Order results in firebase using reactjs axios

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios

I'm new using reactjs and firebase.

I have about 40 (but could have thousands) `posts` in firebase like this:

```
posts: {
    id: '1',
    user: 'josh',
    titulo: 'this is post 1',
}
```

I'd like to order posts by date or id or something that I could order newer posts first.

I have this axios to connect to firebase:

```
componentDidMount () {
    axios.get('https://react-my-app-xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
    .then( response => {
        this.setState({posts: response.data})
    })
    .catch( error => {
            this.setState({error: true});
    });
}
```

any ideas how can I use axios to order posts in firebase?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think sorting your data in client would be a good idea. You could use the [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) to make your API call. The library has built-in methods you could use to [sort and filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: Thnaks for your answer, I will try the sdk!

Comment: No problem, if it helps, it would be great if you mark this as the correct answer, thanks!